# Zivot Andrews unit root test: Why is the p-value 0.162 nonsignificant but the test statistic -20 is highly significant?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, unit-root

```r
############################### 
# Zivot-Andrews Unit Root Test # 
################################ 
    
Call:
lm(formula = testmat)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
 -4626   -835    -11    877   4014 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -78.2937   150.3974   -0.52    0.603  
y.l1         -0.0118     0.0487   -0.24    0.808  
trend        -1.1442     1.0892   -1.05    0.294  
du          513.8623   268.0322    1.92    0.056 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1380 on 421 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.0121,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.00507 
F-statistic: 1.72 on 3 and 421 DF,  p-value: 0.162

Teststatistic: -20.767 
Critical values: 0.01= -5.34 0.05= -4.8 0.1= -4.58 

Potential break point at position: 213
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reported (see below for some reproducible code) p-value belongs to the F-test statistic of the regression model of the test regression and tests if all regression coefficients of that test regression are zero. I hope this also becomes clearer for the reformatted code.

Hence it is for an altogether different null hypothesis than that of the ZA unit root test (one might indeed argue whether it is necessary that this information is printed in `summary`).

```r
library(urca)

ZA.urt <- ur.za(cumsum(rnorm(100)))
summary(ZA.urt)

> summary(ZA.urt)

################################ 
# Zivot-Andrews Unit Root Test # 
################################    

Call:
lm(formula = testmat)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.25973 -0.47726 -0.00929  0.54114  2.29491 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.181162   0.324480  -3.640 0.000443 ***
y.l1         0.855933   0.041569  20.590  < 2e-16 ***
trend        0.001609   0.004293   0.375 0.708669    
du           1.191977   0.406882   2.930 0.004250 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8506 on 95 degrees of freedom
  (1 Beobachtung als fehlend gelöscht)
Multiple R-squared:  0.9281,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9258 
F-statistic: 408.7 on 3 and 95 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Teststatistic: -3.4657 
Critical values: 0.01= -5.34 0.05= -4.8 0.1= -4.58 

Potential break point at position: 80
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help.